# How to implement server & multi-clients "communication"?

Tags: python

What I aim to do is to fulfill a mutual communication between one server but multiple clients.
Here is the Server part I wrote:

```
Import subprocess, time, socket, fileinput
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host=''
port = 2000
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(2) # here 2 means the maximum number of clients that can connect to the server is 2
conn,addr = s.accept()
for data in fileinput.input('some file I previously created')
    conn.send(data)
conn.close()
```

So, here pretty much is the client-server communication. (Only the Server part). The question is: This script can implement communication between one client and one server.

How to fulfill communication between one server and multiple clients. Let's say I have 6 numbers in the file. I wish to transmit the first 3 to client-A, the 4th to client-B and the rest to client-C.

How to make this happen?

I appreciate your precious and experienced skills.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com).

Comment: I should test that and give you my feedback.

Comment: @user495511: on Linux it tends to be installed already, on Windows you will need to install it. It's not in the Python core; read the site that I gave a link to.